# Disabling gedit backup files (filename~ tilde)

Tags: command-line, backup, gedit, dconf, gsettings

How can I get the following command to change for the root user as well?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor create-backup-copy false
```

This command should disable gedit backup files. It seems to work for the current user "vagrant" as shown in the screenshot below, but not root.

[image]

It is important to mention that this command needs to be run as the current user "vagrant" as it is part of a script.

```
Ubuntu 12.04
Kernel 3.2.0-58-generic-pae
GNOME  3.2.1
Running Linux in a Vagrant VM on Windows 8 using Virtual Box
```

Comment: See also [Why user should never use normal sudo to start graphical application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application) because I see that you make a big mistake using `sudo gedit`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I followed through with your suggestions, and yes AskUbuntu is much different than many Forum/Q&A based websites. I've refocused the question and hopefully made things a bit easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo -i
```

This worked!

If you are confident that the current user has the appropriate privileges to sudo, then the following command will change the root users gedit preferences from the current user

```
sudo -i gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor create-backup-copy false
```

However, instead of disabling the backup files at all, you could relocate them to another folder. Rmano provided the following script:

mkdir ~/TILDEBACKUPS

```
#!/bin/bash

find $HOME/* -name TILDEBACKUPS -prune -or -name "*~" -print -exec mv {} $HOME/TILDEBACKUPS/ \;
```

Also, as pointed out by Rinzwind, scripting gsettings may require a lot of maintenance as schema names change.

Finally, there was a bigger mistake here that led me to even asking this question. Thanks to  Radu Rădeanu, opening the file with "sudo gedit filename" will cause all sorts of issues discussed in [Why user should never use normal sudo to start graphical application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application)

A better way to open filename in gedit is:

```
gksudo gedit filename
```

Thank you for everyone's help

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted a root `gedit` to not create backups then simply disable in root's `gsettings` (editing root's `gsettings` should be done with care & in only some limited places).

```
sudo -i
```

then

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor create-backup-copy false
```

Note that starting in 13.10, I'd probably stick to `gksudo gedit` or just use a cli editor such as `nano`.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is correct. I was able to achieve the desired effect using "sudo -i gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor create-backup-copy false" I want this particular setting to apply to both root and the vagrant user

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the way to clean all the backup files is not so complex... you can do it with this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

find $HOME/* -name TildeBackups -prune -or -name "*~" -print -exec mv {} $HOME/TildeBackups/ \;
```

...just run it and it will move all *~ files under your home folder to the `TildeBackup` folder on your home (which you need to create beforehand).

When you discover you needed a backup is too late...

Answer (score 0):

To disable it run the command:

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor create-backup-copy false
```

Now to clean your home from these files(files ending with ~) run this simple command:

```
find ~ -name "*~" -delete
```